# Pegando o valor da tabela com ckeckbox e passando para o controller com AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, tabela-html

Boa Noite!

Estou com um problema que ainda não encontrei uma solução

Primeiro eu faço uma consulta no banco de dados que me retorna alguns valores e eu jogo dentro de uma tabela com `ng-repeat`

### Tabela

```
<tr ng-repeat="contrato in contratos">
<td>{{contrato.NOME}}</td>
<td>{{contrato.CPF_CONTRATO}}</td>
<td>{{contrato.NUMERO_CONTRATO}}</td>
<td>{{contrato.FISICO}}</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
</tr>
```

até ai tudo bem, mas eu preciso fazer com que ao clicar no `checkbox` eu pegue o `NUMERO_CONTRATO` e passe para uma `function` no meu `controller`

### Function

```
$scope.PegaContrato = function () {

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adicione o argumento `ng-click` ao seu checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="PegaContrato(contrato.NUMERO_CONTRATO)">
```

Depois modifique a sua função para receber o valor:

```
$scope.PegaContrato = function (numero_contrato) {
    console.log(numero_contrato);
}
```

Pronto, assim você já consegue saber qual o contrato foi selecionado.

**UPDATE:**
Se houver necessidade de remover um contrato selecionado (ação inversa), adicione o argumento `ng-checked` ao seu checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
    ng-click="PegaContrato(contrato.NUMERO_CONTRATO)"
    ng-checked="contratos.indexOf(contrato.NUMERO_CONTRATO) > -1">
```

Altere a sua função:

```
$scope.contratos = [];
$scope.PegaContrato = function (numero_contrato) {
    //console.log(numero_contrato);
    var index = $scope.contratos.indexOf(numero_contrato);

    // se já selecionou o contrato, então remove (nesse caso o checkbox foi desmarcado)
    if (index > -1)
        $scope.contratos.splice(index, 1);
    // se selecionou um novo contrato, adiciona ao array
    else
      $scope.contratos.push(numero_contrato);

    // print em tela do array com os contratos selecionados
    console.log(contratos);
}
```

Comment: E tem como passar mais de um contrato ?